# Using existing field values in django update query

Tags: django, django-models

I want to update a bunch of rows in a table to set the id = self.id. How would I do the below?

```
from metadataorder.tasks.models import Task
tasks = Task.objects.filter(task_definition__cascades=False)
        .update(shared_task_id=self.id)
```

The equivalent SQL would be:

```
update tasks_task t join tasks_taskdefinition d
    on t.task_definition_id = d.id
set t.shared_task_id = t.id
    where d.cascades = 0
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set the `shared_task_id` for each row to the `id` value in that row, or do you want to set the `shared_task_id` for many rows to a single value that you're getting from `self`?

Comment: For each row set it to itself

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do this using an [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F):

```
from django.db.models import F
tasks = Task.objects.filter(task_definition__cascades=False)
    .update(shared_task_id=F('id'))
```

There are some restrictions on what you can do with `F` objects in an `update` call, but it'll work fine for this case:

> Calls to update can also use `F expressions` to update one field based on the value of another field in the model.
>
> However, unlike `F()` objects in `filter` and `exclude` clauses, you can’t introduce joins when you use `F()` objects in an `update` – you can only reference fields local to the model being updated. If you attempt to introduce a join with an `F()` object, a `FieldError` will be raised[.]

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon this topic and noticed Django's limitation of updates with foreign keys, so I now use raw SQL in Django:

```
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE a JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id SET a.myField = b.myField")
```

Comment: For PostgreSQL: `UPDATE a SET myField = b.myField FROM b WHERE a.b_id = b.id`