# Update a Queryset in Django instead of For loop

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am trying to update a queryset, I would like to calculate a Field order

```
class Temporal(model.Models):
   id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
   name=models.CharField(max_length=60)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

in my app it is important to order_by created_at, and then assing a order as index, everytime a new object is created assing value cero and the rest of the objects the need to be plus +1, but I would like to do using queryset instead of using a for loop :

```
items = Temporal.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
for index, item enumerate(items):
   item.order=index + 1
   item.save()
```

assuming thousands of items on the database this would be very slow... thanks in advance

Comment: You already have the primary key which would have the same order as `created_at` right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using existing field values in django update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337619/using-existing-field-values-in-django-update-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the django documentation you can use `bulk_update` so checkout the link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update

Try something like the following:

```
items = Temporal.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
for index, item enumerate(items):
   item.order=index + 1
Temporal.objects.bulk_update(items, ['order'])
```

That's it.

Comment: becus i have order as a unique_together field, i get the error: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry'. Any suggestion on how i could solve this?